# VIM :helptags with variable directory

Tags: vim

I want to use VIM for keeping a sort of log book, behaving like VIM help, like in [this VIM tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip823). I have it all set up, except for one little thing: how can I trick `:helptags` into taking a variable as an argument? I don't want to hard-code the path.

What I want to do is basically this:

```
let g:NotesFilePath='~/Dropbox/notes'
nmap ,nh :helptags g:NotesFileDir<CR>
```

Of course, then it says `E150: Not a directory: g:NotesFileDir`

So the question is: is there a way to trick `:helptags` into taking a variable argument, or do I have to hard-code the path?

EDIT: I did manage to add the directory to my runtime path, so the `tags` file is picked up by VIM, so that's not a problem.

Oh, and symlinking isn't really an option for me: I want to save the file in a Dropbox so I can share it between my machines (including one Windows box).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nmap ,nh :exe "helptags" . g:NotesFileDir<CR>
```

Comment: Although this is a fairly simple example, it's good practice to use fnameescape() when giving a filename to :exe (shellescape() if the :exe is executing a shell command).  E.g., this would end up being: nmap ,nh :exe "helptags " . fnameescape(g:NotesFileDir)<CR>